# JS - Create addEventListener inside the block of a function?

Tags: javascript

I have the following js module:

```js
if (!CookieManager.getCookie("consent")) {
  const modal = new Modal("#cookieConsentModal");

  // Open the cookie consent pop-up if necessary
  modal.show();

  //
  // Listen the 'allow' and 'decline' buttons
  //

  $("#cookieConsentAllowButton").on("click", () => {
    CookieManager.consent = true;
  });

  $("#cookieConsentDeclineButton").on("click", () => {
    CookieManager.consent = false;
    CookieManager.deleteAllCookies();
  });
}
```

And I have thought to refactor this script to something like:

```js
(() => {
  if (CookieManager.getCookie("consent")) return;

  const modal = new Modal("#cookieConsentModal");

  modal.show();

  $("#cookieConsentAllowButton").on("click", () => {
    CookieManager.consent = true;
  });

  $("#cookieConsentDeclineButton").on("click", () => {
    CookieManager.consent = false;
    CookieManager.deleteAllCookies();
  });
})();
```

Is it correct to create the event listeners inside the block of a function in JavaScript?

Comment: Absolutely. Where else will you create it?  Are you asking whether you should move the handler code to another function and call that function from the on("click") method? For a small handler, that seems like a lot of work.

Comment: @Nikkorian I was creating it linearly, inside the module's script. I mean, not inside a function block. Thats why I created the IIFE, to refactor the long conditional block, by returning from the function.

Comment: But isn't the first version inside another function that I can't see? Basically almost all JS code is inside one function or another. Having said that, I don't see the point of the change you have made. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Argh - read the rest of your comment. My view FWIW is that if you are trying to reduce the size of your blocks of code, an IIFE doesn't achieve much - I would create a named function and make a call to that.

Comment: @Nikkorian Okey, thank you. I answered the question with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Nikkorian suggestion:

```js
import $ from "jquery";
import { Modal } from "bootstrap";

import { CookieManager } from "../lib/cookies";
import { CONSENT_COOKIE } from "../utils/cookies";

/**
 * Displays the cookie consent pop-up to the user.
 *
 * @private
 * @function getCookieConsent
 * @returns {void} Nothing.
 * @requires module:CookieManager~CookieManager
 * @requires module:Cookies/Constants.CONSENT_COOKIE
 */
function getCookieConsent() {
  if (CookieManager.getCookie(CONSENT_COOKIE.name)) return;

  const modal = new Modal("#cookieConsentModal");

  modal.show();

  $("#cookieConsentAllowButton").on("click", () => {
    CookieManager.consent = true;
  });

  $("#cookieConsentDeclineButton").on("click", () => {
    CookieManager.consent = false;
    CookieManager.deleteAllCookies();
  });
};

getCookieConsent();
```